# Elasticsearch, explain all the documents returned by a query

Tags: elasticsearch

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html

shows two endpoints which explains a `document`'s score

```
GET /<index>/_explain/<id>

POST /<index>/_explain/<id>
```

Are there a way to get explanation for all the documents returned by a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this below endpoint to explain all the documents returned by a query

```
POST <index-name>/_search?explain=true
```

And in the body part you can write your search query